# Insert template without overriding childs in Thymeleaf (default head template)

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am used to `th:insert` and `th:replace` but I need a way to include a fragment in a header without overriding other tags inside head.

I tried this, but the `home.css` head gets completely overwritten:

home.html:

```
<head th:include="fragments/head :: genericHead">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
```

Head template:

```
<head th:fragment="genericHead">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
</head>
```

I want some way to do a th:add or similar in order to have both links as childs of `head` and which results in something like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [th:block](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag) together with `th:include` / `th:replace`

Your `home.html` would look like:

```
<head>
    <th:block th:include="fragments/head :: genericHead"></th:block>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/home.css">
</head>
```

And the fragment would look exactly the same:

```
<head th:fragment="genericHead">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
</head >
```

The `th:block` will execute the `include` and then it will desappear (so it can be a `include` or also a `replace`, it doesn't matter after all) leaving us with the content of the fragment tag.